# Delete a discord dm from a bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so my question is how i can delete a message sent by a bot thats sends dc invites to users.
Here is my code:

```
                        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
                          .get(user.id);
                          if(array.length >= 1){
                          if(message.member.roles.cache.has('529770658914369537')){
                            const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Gaming Lounge')
                            let invite = await channel.createInvite({
                              maxAge: 60000, 
                              maxUses: 1 
                            }).catch(console.error);
                            client.users.cache.get(array[0]).send(`Here is your Invite: ${invite}`);
                            array.splice(0, 1);
                            console.log(array);
                            reaction.users.remove(user);
```

Comment: In DM? You can’t delete messages by other users in DM?

Comment: i mean i want to delete the message that the bot sent

Comment: You can just do `message.delete()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation you can get a rough idea. essentially you send the message and store the resolved promise (use await) into a variable. this variable contains the delete method which is pretty self explanatory

---

```js
if (command === "king") {
    const DELAY = 5000 // delay before deleting message
    const kingMessage = await message.channel.send("test");
    kingMessage.delete({ timeout: DELAY })
}
```

---

Link to documentation for delete method: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete

Comment: Make sure to use the correct parameter for delay options: `<Message>.delete({ timout: DELAY })`